# jQuery rebind $(window).scroll() after a successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made this infinitely scrolling script, but I can't rebind the window scroll after I unbinded it. Here's the script:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var mostOfTheWayDown = ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 2 / 3;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= mostOfTheWayDown) {
            $(window).unbind('scroll');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'loadmore',
                data: {lastrank: lastrank},
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(json){
                    //some work here
                    $(window).bind('scroll');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

How can I rebind the window scroll after a successful ajax call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var scrollFunction = function(){
        var mostOfTheWayDown = ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 2 / 3;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= mostOfTheWayDown) {
            $(window).unbind("scroll");
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadmore",
                data: {lastrank: lastrank},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json){
                    //some work here

                    $(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    $(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback function to the `.bind()` method that does whatever it is you want to happen when the scroll event fires. You'll also want to call `unbind('scroll')` first, so you don't end up with two functions being executed every time the user scrolls.

Answer (score -1):

Similar way to other answers, but with binding instead.

```
$(function(){

  function scrollStuff() {

    var mostOfTheWayDown = ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 2 / 3;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= mostOfTheWayDown)
    {
      $(window).unbind('scroll');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore',
        data: {lastrank: lastrank},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(json){
          //some work here
          $(window).bind('scroll', scrollStuff);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  $(window).bind('scroll', scrollStuff);
});
```

Comment: I changed the unbind to after the if statement. The reason to do an immediate unbind then bind is because elements can have more than one event binded to them and this can cause unwanted effects that happen multiple times in one go. It could be possible that every time the user scrolls, the same event is getting binded over and over again.

Comment: @micha is that comment for me?

Comment: @user1099531 No, you need to look at the history of my script, originally i had   $(window).unbind('scroll').bind('scroll', scrollStuff); as a line, which he thought was unnecessary. I moved the unbind because I wanted to match your original script.