# Get new window height after jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery

I feel like the answer to this question is going to be embarrassingly simple, but it's eating up a lot of time and I can't see the solution. I'm making a simple infinite scroll function, and need the script to recognize the new height of the window after loading more content. The value is always the same as first load time. I based this latest code on [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249047/jquery-rebind-window-scroll-after-a-successful-ajax-call), but it's still not working. Thoughts?

```
var scrollFunction = function(){
        var myTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var myHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        if (myTop >= myHeight){ 
            $(window).unbind("scroll");
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ping/thumbs.php',
                data: 'foo=bar',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".thumbnails").append(data);
                    $(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        };
    };
    $(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The height of the `window` is the size of the browser window.  You want the height of the `body`.  `window` height only changes when the browser is resized.

Comment: `$(document).height()` can be used

Comment: Getting the height of the `window` and `document` is better to do directly. Every speed improvement is good improvement ;)

Comment: I agree with you as the function is bound to `window scroll event`, otherwise i dont believe that every speed improvement is good and loves to follow `convenience over convention`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the height of the window is the height of the browser window. If you want the height of the document you have to use `document` instead of `window`. `document.height` or get the height of the body: `jQuery('body').height()`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        //alert("window changed");
        resizeBlocks();
    });

});


function resizeBlocks() {
    var clientWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var clientHeight = jQuery(window).height();
     ......................
    jQuery(".maindatacontent").height(clientHeight);
}
```

this can be called every time anything resize.

hth